# Error: Unreachable code when trying to return two variables from a function.

Tags: java

This program accesses a file called *indata.txt*, which is saved in the same folder as the program itself. It is just a simple text file with the words saved in it:
green yellow blue red

Using a Tokenizer, these color words are saved into an array called `String [] myarray;`

The `int numTokens;` is supposed to count what number of the array each word gets saved in.

If `numTokens = 4;`, then `myarray [numTokens]` = `myarray [4]`

Then the array is run in reverse order.

In the method `public static int mymethod`, the for-loop uses numTokens to run the array through.

The variable `int len;` is supposed to count how many letters the longest word has.

Then the value is supposed to be returned to the main method

`public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException`
, and then the value will get printed out.

Then, the variable `int indexvalue;` is supposed to count the place of the longest word in the array.

For example: green = 0, yellow = 1, blue = 2, red = 3.

Then the longest word in the array should be printed out using the `int indexvalue;`

```
System.out.println("The largest length of the array is " +myarray [indexvalue]);
```

However, the program does not work as it should. This error message appears in the Compiler Output:

**Error:** Unreachable code

I need to return **both** variables to the main method to print them out.

What, if anything, is wrong with my program?

```
 `import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyFileReader
{
  public static int mymethod (String [] myarray, int len, int numTokens, int length, int lengths, int indexvalue) {
    for (numTokens = 3; numTokens >=0; numTokens-- ) {
      length = lengths;
      lengths= myarray [numTokens].length();
      if (length > lengths) {
        len = length;
        indexvalue = numTokens;
      }
      else {
        len = lengths;
      }
    }
    return len;
    return indexvalue;            // error is here
  }
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
  {
    int len =0;
    int length =0;
    int lengths =0;
    int indexvalue =0;

    String s1;
    String s2;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("indata.txt"));

    s1 = br.readLine();

    System.out.println ("The line is " + s1);
    System.out.println ("The line has " + s1.length() + " characters");

    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Breaking the line into tokens we get:");

    int numTokens = 0;
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (s1);

    String [] myarray;
    myarray = new String[4];

    while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
      s2 = st.nextToken();
      myarray [numTokens]= s2;
      numTokens++;
      System.out.println ("    Token " + numTokens + " is: " + s2);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    for (numTokens = 3; numTokens >= 0; numTokens--) {
    System.out.println("Value of array is " +myarray [numTokens]);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println("Largest length value is " + mymethod(myarray, len, numTokens, length, lengths, indexvalue));
    System.out.println("Index value is " + mymethod(myarray, len, numTokens, length, lengths, indexvalue));
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println("The largest length of the array is " +myarray [indexvalue]);
  }
}`
```

Comment: You can't have two return statements in a row, as the second one will never be execute

Comment: Well then how do I return the second one then?

Comment: If you must, suppose the easiest would be to return an int[], with the two values that you need.

Answer (score 4):

```
return len;
return indexvalue;            // error is here
```

Java does not allow code that will never be executed. This includes *any* code following a return statement. Since a return statement exits the method, anything after it can never be read. Usually multiple returns are branched in if-else conditions such that only one of them can ever be executed.

Edit: If the idea is to return multiple variables at once, you can either return an array or return a custom object from a new Class that has the fields you require.

Comment: I need to return both variables to the main method.

Answer (score 3):

A method can only execute one `return` statement. Once it returns a value, the program exits the method. `return indexvalue` is unreachable because it is after another return statement.

Comment: While I understand your point (and the point you are making is correct), a method may have many `return` statements, so long as they resolve in such away as not to truncate other functionality, but maybe that might be just to confusing for the OP to deal with right now. I'm old school so I believe in only one entry/exit point any ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I'm aware a method can have multiple return statements but only execute one of them; I've edited my original answer for clarity now.

Answer (score 3):

If you must return two values, try an int array

```
public static int[] mymethod (String [] myarray, int len, int numTokens, int length, int lengths, int indexvalue){
int[] result = new int[2];
.
.
.
result[0] = len;
result[1] = indexvalue;
return result;
}
```

A better solution would be to create an object with these properties and return that instead. Cheers.

Comment: This is probably what I would do. The alternative would be to create a class that contains the info you want to return.

Comment: Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int.

Comment: @Galaxy You need to change your return type in your method declaration.

Answer (score 2):

This  method 'mymethod' gives only first return statement and then dies, 
you can return an array, or just delete the 'len' argument and return other statement.

Or you can do that:

```
System.out.println("Largest length value is " + myarray[numTokens].length());
```

And then clean up methods' arguments as they look messy, there is no need for this many arguments, you can get confused.

Comment: I strongly agree with the last part. Having variables named `len`, `lengths` and `length` in one method makes me cringe.